# Objective C reflection for C-type vars

Tags: objective-c, c, reflection

I have few `extern` variables declared in `@interface` block of my `.h` file. They are assigned in `.m` file. In one method of my `@interface` (preferable class method) I want to enumerate over these variables via reflection, but I have no any idea is it possible at all, and how is yes ?
Example of my code:

```
Consts.h

extern NSString *MyConst1;
extern NSString *MyConst2;

Consts.m

NSString *MyConst1 = nil;
NSString *MyConst2 = nil;

+ (void)load {
  MyConst1 = ...;
  MyConst2 = ...;
}

+ (void)someMethod {
  // i could use class_copyIvarList for objective c properties/ivars, 
  // but is it possible to get that MyConts1 and MyConst2 via reflection ? 
  // I understand, that C have different namespace,
  // and I have no experience with it. 
}
```

Comment: There is no reflection in C. If you want to enumerate over values, put them into an array. If you want to set values to them, enumerate over pointers to them.

Comment: @Sulthan putting into array is obvious. i'm interested not to make a lot of duplicated code. Maybe objc have some runtime magic for c stuff ? there is difference in c vars put in the @ interface and not, so maybe they could be reflected somehow through objc ?

Comment: Objective-C does no magic with C. Objective-C creates objects composed from C structs, with additional metadata that allow reflection on *Obj-C* objects. But C is just C.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C supports reflection for Objective-C objects. The reflection works because every Obj-C class contains the necessary metadata (property names, method names etc.).

Objective-C doesn't in any way change the C language. Objective-C runtime is basically implemented in C and the compiler only translates Objective-C into C function calls.

No, you cannot use reflection for global variables outside the context of any Objective-C class.

If you want reflection, wrap them into a class.

However, note, that using reflection is almost never a good solution. Usually it is abused to solve a problem that is caused by bad architecture.

Answer (score 0):

There are no class variables in ObjC. Only instances can have variables in ObjC. Even if you declare a global between @interface or @implementation and @end, it will still just be a global, ObjC doesn't actually know about it.

Only the ObjC parts in a .m file support introspection. One alternative approach would be to create a singleton that has methods returning your constants, then you can enumerate its methods. Alternately, you could create a function/method that returns an array of your constants. To avoid duplication of your constants and array, you could use the X Macro technique:

```
#define OSC_TYPE_CONSTANTS   X(MyConst1) \
                             X(MyConst2)

// Header:
#define X(n) extern NSString* n;
OSC_TYPE_CONSTANTS
#undef X

// Implementation:
#define OSC_STRINGIFY(n) #n
#define X(n) NSString* n = OSC_STRINGIFY(n);
OSC_TYPE_CONSTANTS
#undef X

#define X(n) n,
NSArray* gAllTypesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: OSC_TYPE_CONSTANTS nil];
#undef X
```

What do you need this for? Are these constants compiled directly into your app, or is this in a framework from which they are exported? Depending on that, there may be solutions involving CFBundle's CFBundleGetDataPointerFromName or dlsym.